# How to get pedefined field value mentioned in QuickAction?

Tags: apex, quickaction, describefieldresult

Quick Action : **SendMail**

I want to get predefined values using Apex

[image]

```
QuickAction.QuickActionRequest req = new QuickAction.QuickActionRequest();
  req.quickActionName = Schema.Case.QuickAction.SendEmail;
```

How to get value mentioned in **ValidatedFromAddress**  pfv ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [QuickAction.describeQuickActions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_system_quickaction.htm) and then [get default values](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_quickaction_describequickactionresult.htm#apex_class_quickaction_describequickactionresult).

```
List<QuickAction.DescribeQuickActionResult> result =
        QuickAction.DescribeQuickActions(new List<String> {
                'Case.SendEmail'});


System.debug(result[0].getDefaultValues());
```

Comment: I've tried your code - your system.debug showing **no value** () .
Well , the predefined field **ValidatedFromAddress** contain formula field , i want to get the resultat of that formula using Apex .

Comment: working for my custom quick action. :/